# Why can't MATLAB save uint8 type matrix?

Tags: matlab, save

Here is the code:

```
x = rand(5)*100;
save('pqfile.txt','x','-ascii','-tabs')
```

The above works, but:

```
x = rand(5)*100;
x = uint8(x);
save('pqfile.txt','x','-ascii','-tabs')
```

says:

```
Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
    Variable 'x' not written to file.
```

Does anyone know why this happens? How come I can't save the data when it is uint8. I have to read data into a VHDL testbench so was experimenting. I guess the only option is to save my 8 bit unsigned integer values in 2d array using printf then read into the test bench.

Comment: From `help save`: _For ASCII file formats, the save function has the following limitations: [...] each variable must be a two-dimensional __double__ or __char__ array._ Can't you just save `y = double(x)` instead of `x`? Note, however, that that will write things like `8.1000000e+01` instead of `81` in the text file. Or try `dlmwrite('pqfile.txt ',x)`

Comment: This is not a VHDL question, so please remove the tag

Comment: The data written by MATLAB is a 2D array to be read into a VHDLA test bench

Answer (score 3):

**ASCII option**

The `save` method is somewhat restrictive in what it can support, and then it uses floating point notation to represent your numbers which bloats your file when dealing with a limited range of numbers like you are (i.e. uint8, 0 to 255).

Check out `dlmwrite` as an alternative ([documentation here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)).

It takes the filename to write/save to, the variable to store, and some additional parameters, like the delimiter you want to separate your values with.

For your example, it looks like this

```
x = rand(5)*100;
x = uint8(x);
dlmwrite('pqfile.txt',x,'\t');
```

**Binary option**

If you are looking to stored your uint8 data as single bytes then you probably want go with a custom binary file instead instead of ASCII. (Yes, you can convert uint8 to single ASCII characters but you run into issues with these values being interpreted with your delimiters; newlines or tabs.)

```
fid=fopen('pqfile.dat','wb');
if(fid>2)
    fwrite(fid,size(x),'*uint8');  % Note: change data type here you are dealing with more than 255 rows or columns
    fwrite(fid,x','*uint8'); % Transpose x (with x') so it is stored in row order.
    fclose(fid);
else
    fprintf(1,'Could not open the file for writing.\n');
end
```

I'm not sure what type of parser you are using for your VHDL, but this will pack your data into a file with a short header of the expected dimensions followed by one long row of your serialized data.

To read it back in with MATLAB, you can do this:

```
fid = fopen('pqfile.dat','rb');
szX = fread(fid,2,'uint8');
x = fread(fid,szX,'*uint8')';  % transpose back if you are dealing with matlab.
fclose(fid);
```

The transpose operations are necessary for MATLAB because it reads data column-wise, whereas most other languages (in my experience) read row-wise.